# How to iterate crop raster in R using a moving window?

Tags: r, for-loop, raster, r-raster, terra

I want to crop a raster using a bbox or a known extent, i.e., 10 pixels in row and col.

Below you can see a reproducible example:

```
library(terra)
r <- terra::set.ext(rast(volcano), terra::ext(0, nrow(volcano), 0, ncol(volcano)))
plot(r)

xmin <- xmin(r)
ymax <- ymax(r)
rs <- res(r)

n <- 10 # i.e. of rows and cols size
xmax <- xmin + n * rs[1] 
ymin <- ymax - n * rs[2]

x <- crop(r, c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
plot(x)
```

[image: plot x]

The intended loop is to:

- To go through all the raster (`r`) length cropping and save each raster piece temporarily into data.frame (or data.table, raster, spatraster, list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be useful to have more context about why you would do this. It is also not clear from your question if you want the cropped areas to overlap; I assume you do not want that.

You can probably use `terra::makeTiles` but if that does not apply you could so something like:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(volcano)
n <- 10
```

Get the starting cells of interest

```
rows <- seq(1, nrow(r), by=n)
cols <- seq(1, ncol(r), by=n)    
cells <- cellFromRowColCombine(r, rows, cols)
```

Get the coordinates

```
# upper-left coordinates of the starting cells 
xy <- xyFromCell(r, cells)
rs <- res(r)
xy[,1] <- xy[,1] - rs[1]/2
xy[,2] <- xy[,2] + rs[2]/2

# add the lower-right coordinates of the end cell
xy <- cbind(xy[,1], xy[,1] + n*rs[1], xy[,2] - n*rs[2], xy[,2])
```

And loop

```
x <- lapply(1:nrow(xy), function(i) {
         crop(r, xy[i,])
       })
```

Verify

```
e <- lapply(x, \(i) ext(i) |> as.polygons()) |> vect()
plot(r)
lines(e, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

[image]

```
sapply(x, dim) |> t() |> head()
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   10    1
#[2,]   10   10    1
#[3,]   10   10    1
#[4,]   10   10    1
#[5,]   10   10    1
#[6,]   10   10    1
```

Or use an alternative approach based on the start- and end-cell numbers

```
srows <- seq(1, nrow(r), by=n)
scols <- seq(1, ncol(r), by=n)
erows <- pmin(nrow(r), srows+n-1)
ecols <- pmin(ncol(r), scols+n-1)
scell <- cellFromRowColCombine(r, srows, scols)
ecell <- cellFromRowColCombine(r, erows, ecols)
cells <- cbind(scell, ecell)

x <- lapply(1:nrow(cells), function(i) {
        e <- ext(r, cells[i,])
        crop(r, e)
    })
```

Comment: Hey @Robert Hijmans. Thanks again for answering another post. 

Here, at the alternative answer above I'm receiving this errors below:

`x <- lapply(1:nrow(cells), function(i) {
  e <- ext(r, cells[i,])
  crop(r, e)
})`

**Error in .local(x, ...) : unused argument (c(1, 559))**

Comment: Ah, you need the dev version of terra for that, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

Using `terra` data, by your approach, which I like:

```
library(terra)
r <- terra::set.ext(rast(volcano), terra::ext(0, nrow(volcano), 0, ncol(volcano)))
```

Then we need extents that have 4 values (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax), [for indices {i,j,k,l}} we then want to traverse the raster from top left to top right, then again stepping down, and down till we get to bottom right [for indices {o,p}], then a further crop [for index {q}]. This is a pretty deep nesting for `for` loops, and in the interest of preserving mental...it might be better to make some helpers.

```
x_mtx <- matrix(c(seq(0,70,10), seq(10,80,10)), ncol = 2)
y_mtx <- matrix(c(seq(51, 1, -10), seq(61, 11, -10)), ncol = 2)
```

these eliminate indices i:l, then we make our extents:

```
crop_exts <- vector(mode = 'list', length= 48L)
for(p in 1:6){
  for(o in 1:8){
    crop_exts[[p]][[o]] <- ext(x_mtx[o, 1], x_mtx[o, 2], y_mtx[p, 1], y_mtx[p, 2])
  }
}
# check our work
crop_exts[[1]][[1]] |> as.vector()
#xmin xmax ymin ymax 
#0   10   51   61 
crop_exts[[6]][[8]] |> as.vector()
#xmin xmax ymin ymax 
#  70   80    1   11
```

Looks like top left to bottom right. And noting the [[1]][[1]], [[6]][[8]], we have a second nested {p, o} loop as above in view of our indexing here to pull out the crops:

```
cropped_r <- vector(mode='list', length = 48L)# edit, establish outside `for` 
for(p in 1:6){
 for(o in 1:8){
   cropped_r[[p]][[o]] <- crop(r, crop_exts[[p]][[o]])
 }
}
plot(cropped_r[[1]][[1]])
plot(cropped_r[[6]][[8]])
```

Possibly easier, overall, is to generate the complete extent matrix, dim(48,4) in this case, but couldn't wrap my head around it, and keep in mind indices, and preserve my mental...

Comment: Hey @Chris, the loop is returning an error, see below:
`> for(p in 1:6){
   for(o in 1:8){
     cropped_r[[p]][[o]] <- crop(r, crop_exts[[p]][[o]])
     }
}`
**Error: object 'cropped_r' not found**

Comment: Yup, missed setting up a list to receive the `for` loop operation, probably in cut and paste to here. Also Note, my approach takes no notice of raster resolution, while @robert-hijmans presents where it is central, and shoul find it's way into your workflow. My contribution, such as it is, is to address doing this in a `for`, while, as seen above, all the tools are in `terra` to accomplish better.

Answer (score 1):

Here a function based on @Robert Hijmans answer:

```
create_tiles_ext <- function (
    x,
    n_row = 5000,
    n_col = 5000,
    overlap = 500
) {
  
  require(terra)
  
  # Row and col index where the raster will be split
  rows <- seq(1, nrow(x), by = n_row)
  cols <- seq(1, ncol(x), by = n_col)
  
  # Index of cells that will be in the upper-left corner of the tiles
  cells <- cellFromRowColCombine(x, rows, cols)
  # Coordinates of the upper-left corner of the start cells
  xy_ul <- xyFromCell(x, cells)
  
  # Resolution
  rs <- res(x)
  
  # Create matrix of extents (one ext per row)
  xy <- cbind(
    xy_ul[,1],                   # x left
    xy_ul[,1] + n_col * rs[1],   # x right
    xy_ul[,2] - n_row * rs[2],   # y lower
    xy_ul[,2]                    # y upper
  )
  # Matrix of extents with overlaps
  xy_ol <- cbind(
    xy[,1] - overlap * rs[1],
    xy[,2] + overlap * rs[1],
    xy[,3] - overlap * rs[2],
    xy[,4] + overlap * rs[2] 
  )
  
  # Convert matrix to list of extents
  xy_lst    <- as.list(data.frame(t(xy)))
  xy_ol_lst <- as.list(data.frame(t(xy_ol)))
  
  # Expand raster to include external tiles overlaps
  ext(x) <- c(min(xy_ol[,1]), max(xy_ol[,2]), min(xy_ol[,3]), max(xy_ol[,4]))
  
  return(list(
    xy_lst    = xy_lst,
    xy_ol_lst = xy_ol_lst,
    new_ext   = ext(x)
  ))
  
}
```