# How to find slope of Raster using different neighborhood size in R?

Tags: r, raster, terrain, elevation

This is my first question on R so please bear with me.

Basically, I have a Raster and am able to convert it from a DEM Raster to a slope raster. However, when I convert it to a slope raster, I want to be able to change it from calculating the slope using the surrounding 8 neighbors to something larger.

My current code looks like this:

```
#Read Raster
Original_Raster <- raster("output-5km-8192p-000.63m.tif")

#Call Raster min/max details
Original_Raster <- setMinMax(Original_Raster)

#Set new extent to variable
bb <- extent(-2560,2560,-2560,2560)

#Change Raster extent to variable
extent(Original_Raster) <- bb
Original_Raster <- setExtent(Original_Raster, bb, keepres = TRUE)

#Plot Raster
plot(Original_Raster)
title('Original Elevation Model')

crs(Original_Raster) <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs"

#Create slope raster
Original_Raster_Slope = terrain(Original_Raster, 'slope', unit='degrees', neighbors=8)
```

This is the output of the two plots
[DEM Raster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pw25.png)
[Slope Raster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tupc.png)

My resolution is currently 0.625x0.625m.

My current understanding of using terrain() with 8 neighbors is that it creates a 3x3 grid and the center cell is the slope of that grid. In this case it would be a 1.875x1.875m grid (cell size x3). I want a larger grid to calculate the slope of each cell (particularly a 11.875x11.875m grid - roughly 19x19 grid or 360 neighbors... 361 cells minus center cell).

It's imperative that I keep the resolution at 0.625m and not combine them into 5.625m blocks as I would lose a large number of cells to this that I need for random sampling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: First I would recommend using `terra` rather than `raster`. To 'break out' of neighbor = 4 or 8, you might look at either `?terra::focal` or `?terra::viewshed`. The difficulty with `focal` is having to compute 'slope' and the same could be said for `viewshed`, though the inputs to your 'slope' would likely be radically different. I'd crop my raster to something like 4 windows (1 row or column larger for focal as you'll see in ?focal), play around and see what develops. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: centers for `viewshed` could be approached as [moving window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709795/how-to-iterate-crop-raster-in-r-using-a-moving-window) @robert-hijmans answer, then extract the center cell# of each window...