# R terra weighted kernel density estimate of a spatRaster

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

In library terra, the kernel density estimate of values in a spatRaster x can be calculated using:

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(matrix(rnorm(100,10,1), nr = 10, nc = 10))
density(x, plot = F)
```

But there is no way of estimating a weighted KDE. An application would be to estimate the KDE of mean annual temperature for a particular land use, where that land use occupies varying fractions of cells.

The following function estimates a weighted KDE, but there may be more efficient ways of doing this. For large rasters, a sample (either fraction or cell count) can be taken. Any improvements would be most welcome.

```
# Function weighted density of a spatRaster
dwr <- function(x, w, samp = 1, ...){
  compareGeom(x, w, lyrs = TRUE) # check if data and weights are coherent
  w <- subst(w, NA, 0) # convert missing weights to zero
  if(as.numeric(global(w, min)) < 0) return("Warning: Negative weights") # check weights
  n <- global(x, "notNA")[1,] # count valid data
  sz <- if(samp <= 1) round(samp * n) else samp # make sample a count
  if(sz > n) return("Warning: Sample size is too large") # check sample size
  ss <- spatSample(c(x,w), sz, na.rm = TRUE) # take the sample
  ss$wt <- ss[,2]/sum(ss[,2]) # convert weights to fractions
  density(ss[,1], weights = ss$wt, ...) # Calculate density
}

# Run example
x <- rast(matrix(rnorm(100,10,1), nr = 10, nc = 10))
w <- rast(matrix(rpois(100,5), nr = 10, nc = 10))
dwr(x,w)
```

Comment: For partial cell you'll want to look at `exactextractr`, and an approach to areal [moving window -Hijmans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709795/how-to-iterate-crop-raster-in-r-using-a-moving-window), that could be used in conjunction with exactextractr.