# makeTiles with overlap

Tags: r, raster, terra

I need to use the `terra::distance` function on a large raster file, but it seems quite memory intensive.

So, I would like to split the raster in smaller tiles and loop through them to calculate the distance maps. The `terra::makeTiles` function would be perfect, except that it only allows to create tiles that are not overlapping.

This could introduce some artifacts around the edges of the tiles, when calculating the distance.

Is there a function to easily create overlapping tiles?

Comment: Check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709795/how-to-iterate-crop-raster-in-r-using-a-moving-window

Comment: Alternatively, use GDAL command line. Function: `gdal_proximity.py`. See here: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_proximity.html